# Реализация задника в виде кривой фигуры переходящей на соседнюю секцию

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Получил дизайн следующего вида:

[image: Шапка сайта]

[image: Футер]

Как реализовать задники такого вида? Пробовал ставить в качестве основы сам задник, а на него абсолютно размещать сверху контентную часть, но в таком случае при смене задника всё может поехать. Плюс нужно подгонять всё до мелочей и адаптивность самого фона сходит к нулю. Так же приходится подгонять отрицательные отступы. Получается костыль на костыле, что ни есть хорошо. Заказчик упёрся именно в эту версию, так что второй день уже мучаюсь. Спасибо

Comment: Думаю, что помочь здесь может лишь SVG, ибо все стыки разные и картинок не напасёшься, да и позиционировать/масштабировать при адаптиве - не очень, мягко говоря. Есть подозрение, что дизайнер не мужского пола, как минимум))

Comment: а как этот блок выглядит в мобильной версии?

Comment: Верно, не мужского. Адаптив могу дать, но там видоизменённая фигура, о чём я и сказал дизайнеру. Так что адаптив на моё усмотрение